# Вызвать событие click после по элементу, подгруженному через Ajax

Tags: jquery, javascript

Запросом Ajax на странице подгружается элемент **input**.
Как сделать автоматический клик по этому элементу после загрузки на страницу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('#new_inserted_element').trigger('click');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2n9bLm8u/

**N.B.** alert с текстом ERROR выскакивает, потому что нельзя просто так взять и запросить гугл по аяксу. Если урл взять нормальный, должен вываливаться ОК: см. внимательно код.

Comment: Не совсем ясно о `ajaxComplete(function() {}`? Это **callback** в Succes от AJAX?

Comment: Это любое завершение. Но если элемента #new_inserted_element нет, то событие просто не сработает: об этом заботится jQuery.

Comment: Ну так элемент `#new_inserted_element` как раз такие в ответе от Ajax и создается в `posting.done(function( response ) { // here })`.
_____
Т.е. Ваш пример нерабочий.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchu, а в чем проблема после создания элемента кликнуть по нему через trigger('click')?

Comment: Проблема в том, что так не работает:

    posting.done(function( response ) { $('#new_inserted_element').trigger('click');})

Comment: ээ...
 
  >Т.е. Ваш пример нерабочий  

А вот сейчас обидно было!

http://jsfiddle.net/2n9bLm8u/

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, вы сначала проверьте, заходит ли у вас в эту функцию, и если да, то находит ли элемент.

Answer (score 1):

Вам этот клик нужен, чтобы фокус перевести на этот элемент и сразу можно было начать печатать в него?

Если так, есть [`jQuery.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/ewykc8yr/).

Comment: За один только коммент к коду плюсик поставлю.=)   
Надо это как общепринятую практику ввести.    
Ну и за телепатию, так как, похоже, имелось в виду именно это. )

Comment: @knes, я [стараюсь](https://www.google.ru/search?q=для+вопроса+http://hashcode.ru++site:jsfiddle.net) всегда ставить ссылку на исходный вопрос : )

Answer (score 0):

Плохая идея использовать голый слушатель вида:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('#new_inserted_element').trigger('click');
});
```

Это может привести к нежелательным кликам тогда когда не нужно, если вдруг на странице есть еще какие либо другие аяксы. + лучше все события выполнять именно там где они необходимы, что бы потом не думать, что за магия вообще творится )

Посмотрите пример [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bookamba/pen/wvzEQGx?editors=1011)

```
// тут добавляем ваш инпут и ставим на него фокус
let addInput = function (msg) {
  $("body").append("<input id='new-input' type='text' value='' name='name'>");
  /**
  у append нет callback метода
  а значит после добавления элемента в ДОМ, выполните фокусировку через некоторое время, например 100мс
  Этого будет достаточно что бы append отработал и в DOM появился ваш input
  */
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#new-input").focus();
  }, 100);
};

// использую для теста CDN jQuery c cloudflare, потому что они разрешают кросдоменные запросы
let your_url =
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: your_url,
  //dataType: 'json', //раскомитить, если нужно
  data: {},
  success: function (msg) {
    try {
      addInput(msg);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Ошибонька success" + err);
    }
  },
  error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    console.log(textStatus + "dd");
  },
  failure: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    console.log("Ошибонька" + errorMessage);
  }
});
```